# Why the modules in the pic below are Overlapping?

Tags: asynchronous, requirejs, amd

[image]

Let's suppose we are doing this

```
 require(['module1', 'module2', 'module3'], function(m1, m2, m3){   
      //Doing something after they load 
 });
```

What will happen exactly?

I feel this will happen: First the require will construct the filepaths for these modules by using baseUrl or path and then she wil send get request for these modules and will ask O/s kernels to load these files and when done ??? (I guess there is no event loop here)

I am totally confused please help me What will happen ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first graphic the modules are load synchronous, which means module1 is requested and if it was loaded successfully module2 starts loading and so on.

In the second graphic the modules overlapping cause the requests going out after each other but all files are loading asynchronous, which means there is no waiting for one module to get loaded successfully before starting the next request.

So requireJs load all the script asynchronous and waits for all request to get loaded and after this it injects all modules into your function.